# Redirect https request on http localhost

Tags: networking, dns, redirection

I need that when an application on my computer asks for https://example.com/something will redirect to 127.0.0.1:8080/other.
You can suggest me how to configure it on my router or install a tool to do it.
It's a Windows 10 pc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes in your `%windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file enter:

```
127.0.0.1 domain.com
```

Where `domain.com` is the domain name. Like `example.com`